# changing background image of Linearlayout after time in milliseconds with a repetition

Tags: android

I want to chang background image of Linearlayout after time in milliseconds with a repetition.

See link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwthh.png

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain your problem. Not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: See link http://i.imgur.com/XVmVXok.png